# Javascript Array variable name

Tags: javascript

I am trying to learn javascript and I just started trying to learn Arrays

I see problem when I use the array name as "name"

```
var names = ['asdasd','qweqwe'];
names[0];
```

returns "asdasd"

however,

```
var name = ['asdasd','qweqwe'];
name[0];
```

is returning "a"

why is that ? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably in the global scope, so you're really setting `window.name`, and `window.name` already exists and can only be a string.

That's what you're returning, the string from `window.name`, not your `name` variable.

Comment: I don't think [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name) is read-only. Rather, assignments to `window.name` gets converted to a string. So `var name = ['asdasd','qweqwe'];` results in `window.name` being `asdasd,qweqwe`, and `name[0]` produces the first letter `a`.

Comment: @Antony - that is correct, was going a bit fast there, of course you can name the windows. I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because `name`, being a predefined window property is a *string* and `names` is an *array of string*

You may confirm this by printing them individually.

`name` returns "asdasd,qweqwe" and `names` returns ["asdasd", "qweqwe"]